# Dash-to-Dock: How to remove these black stripes?

Tags: gnome-shell, window, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, dock

When I maximize the window, these black bars appear, **how to remove them?** or **How reset dash config?**

**Ubuntu 18.10**, I did edit it's with [Dash-to-Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) extension.

[image: screenshot]